# QPDF how to detect pages size (or ratio)

Tags: pdf, qpdf

How can be detected page size (height x width) with qpdf?

I know that it could be that size is something relative, but at least I could know ratio between height and width (eg. a3, a4).

Comment: Thanks, I'm now using the --json command to get a json report and then parsing for all of the objects with type /Page, given this there is the a /MediaBox property dealing with the informations

Comment: Thanks @KJ, you have directed me to the solution, I will be glad to let you write the answer with the --json and pageposfrom1 options.